# Open navigation drawer by clicking normal button on Fragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

**Want to do**

Open navigation drawer by clicking normal button on Fragment as same as clicking navigation icon.

[Before clicked button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlOpU.png)

[After clicked button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu2ER.png)

**Relation of code and xml**

MainActivity.cs - activity_main.xml

EventFragment.cs - event_fragment.xml

FilterNavi.cs - filter_navigation.xml  (I am not sure that which is the best for FilterNavi.cs Fragment or Activity.)

**Code**
**Error Message**

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

**Code**

EventFragment.cs

```
public class EventFragment : AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener, TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener
{
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    Button btn_drawer ;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.event_fragment, container, false);

        drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout2);

        btn_drawer = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_drawer);
        btn_drawer.Click += Btn_Drawer_Click;
    }

    private void Btn_Drawer_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        drawer.OpenDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
    }
```

filter_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout2"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                    tools:openDrawer="start">

  <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:text="test"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:gravity="center">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

  </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**What I tried**

I tried **getView()** and **getActivity()** but error told me that they don't exist in the current context .

```
m_drawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(Resource.Id.drawer_layout2);
```

I also tried to get **m_drawer** and update **view**.

**m_drawer** was not null but navigation drawer didn't open.

```
        View viewFilter = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.filter_navigation, container, false);
        m_drawer = viewFilter.FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout2);
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.event_fragment, container, false);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442841/how-to-open-navigation-drawer-on-button-click-in-main-fragment

Comment: Thank you for comment. I tried samething but getActivity() makes an error maybe because C#. Do you know instead of getActivity() or other way?

Comment: You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279971/get-current-activity-xamarin-android), It's about how to get activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't open navigation drawer by clicking normal button on Fragment. However I found alternative way.

I use normal Activity which has translucent background on half right side. You can change the width of it by layout_weight. Where I don't want to make translucsent, I set white background.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

**Activity.cs**

```
namespace SMP_Android
{
    // add Theme
    [Activity(Label = "FilterActivity", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent")]
public class FilterActivity : AppCompatActivity // select AppCompatActivity
    {
    }
}
```

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="aa000000"> // add background
```